# Multiple app versions on Google Glass

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I have been working with the GDK for Glass and I have noticed that some of my apps have two different versions installed on Glass.  For example, if I go to Timer, there are two versions, same name, same everything, but I need to choose which one before I can launch the app.  With the app that I am currently creating, there are again two different versions.  So I say, "ok glass, voice trigger" and it asks me to pick from two apps, one being an old version and one being a new one.  I tried using myGlass to manage my apps, but it didn't show my custom apps on it.  Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding [ChromeADB](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromeadb/fhdoijgfljahinnpbolfdimpcfoicmnm?hl=en) to your Chrome browser and use that to help you see (and manage) applications.